# Entity Framework query for data value with more than 1 forward slash

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to search for a record in the table with the following query. The value that I am searching for contains more than 1 forward slashes. e.g. "Temp / Temp2 / Temp3". The following query works fine for normal text but fails for the aforementioned example.

```
var result = (from record in db.someTable
              where record.des == item.name
              select new { no = record.no, }).Single();
```

Comment: So, if you're searching for `"Temp2"`, you want it to find the record with `"Temp / Temp2 / Temp3"`?

Comment: No the value that I am searching for is "Temp / Temp2 / Temp3". This is just one value and not a set of values.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you're saying that `item.name` is equal to `record.des` and using `where record.des == item.name` doesn't find it, then they aren't *really* equal (slashes won't affect an equality comparison). Look carefully for differences in the values. Maybe extra spaces somewhere.

Comment: The point is that even if thery arent equal the query should return empty set however in this case, it simply fails (throws an exception).

Comment: where ıs your error message? be more descriptive

Comment: no Linq Single() will fails if there is no rows returned from so called query with 
"Sequence contains no elements" use SingleOrDefault() it will return null object if rows from sql side is 0

Comment: This aforementioned query of yours will be run find and returns result if item.name = "Temp / Temp2 / Temp3" and database contains the value "Temp / Temp2 / Temp3". you have to check for other alt possibilities for this error

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved using SingleOrDefault()